# how to play dtmf from voice xml

Tags: voicexml

I have application that calls bridge. When call is connected I want my voice xml to enter extension number play dtmf tone 3 times. How that can be done please if possible at all?

Answer (score 4):

You can play back the dtmf as recorded audio when the call is answered. Some recording software, such as [Adobe Audition](http://www.adobe.com/products/audition.html), will create dtmf recordings for you without having to record over the phone. This provides much cleaner dtmf recordings.  Voxeo has some free [dtmf recordings you can download here](https://evolution.voxeo.com/library/audio/prompts/dtmf/index.jsp).

Comment: One caveat: This assumes the far side collecting tones via the audio stream.  Within SIP DTMF is intended to be passed in the messaging stream.  Given that the entire path may not be SIP, many systems support configuration options regarding how DTMF can be forwarded and accepted.

Comment: At the VoiceXML level it should be transparent as to what the telephony connection is. A caveat with sending DTMF over SIP is there are several ways to accomplish this with the SIP standard and not all platforms are compatible in how they handle it.